# How can I mask an image on the ball (circle) in Java?

Tags: java, android

```
@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

    mSurfaceWidth = width;
    mSurfaceHeight = height;
    mBallX = width / 2;
    mBallY = height/(1.1f);
    mVX = 0;
    mVY = 0;
}

private void drawCanvas() {
        Canvas c = mHolder.lockCanvas();
        c.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        c.drawCircle(mBallX, mBallY, RADIUS, paint);
        mHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
    }
```

I want to change `paint` in `c.drawCircle()` to use my image.
What code I should write?

Comment: do you want to put an imagine instead of black background?

Comment: yes! do you know how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
private void drawCanvas() {
    Canvas c = mHolder.lockCanvas();
    c.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);

    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.imagenamefromdrawableRes);
    c.drawBitmap(bmp, mBallX, mBallY - RADIUS, null);
    //c.drawCircle(mBallX, mBallY, RADIUS, paint);
    mHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
}
```